# How to append text to multiple files in one directory using Java

Tags: java, file, text, java-io

I have a lot of .txt files with some data

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
...
```

I want to add the same text, for example `"hello world"` to every txt file from same directory.

i know how to work with one file in that case, but how to deal with multiple files? i have to do that using Java...

Comment: What Java version are you using?

Comment: @deHaar 8 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `java.nio` along with Java 8 features to list the files and perform some action for each one. There is a method to append text to a file.

See this example and read the few comments in the code, please:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // define the directory that contains the text files
    String dir = "U:\\workspace\\git\\ZZ--Temp\\TextFiles";
    Path dirPath = Paths.get(dir);
    // predefine some lines to be appended to every file
    List<String> linesToBeAppended = new ArrayList<>();
    linesToBeAppended.add("Hello new line in the file!");

    try {
        // go through all files in the directory (tested with .txt files only)
        Files.list(dirPath)
            // filter only files
            .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
            .forEach(filePath -> {
                try {
                    // append the predefined text to the file
                    Files.write(filePath, linesToBeAppended, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println("Could not append text to file " 
                            + filePath.toAbsolutePath().toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not list files in " 
                + dirPath.toAbsolutePath().toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the nested `try`-`catch` is necessary due to the different scope of the Java 8 feature `forEach`. It's ugly, but has the advantage that you can distinguish the `Exception`s thrown either by listing the files or accessing one.

**EDIT**
If you want to add a new first line to the file, then you will have to read and re-write the file. See this example, which is just slightly different from the first one:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // define the directory that contains the text files
    String dir = "U:\\workspace\\git\\ZZ--Temp\\TextFiles";
    Path dirPath = Paths.get(dir);

    try {
        // go through all files in the directory (tested with .txt files only)
        Files.list(dirPath)
            // filter only files
            .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
            .forEach(filePath -> {
                // predefine some lines to be appended to every file
                List<String> linesToBeAppended = new ArrayList<>();
                // add the first line as predefined first line
                linesToBeAppended.add("Hello another line in the file!");

                try {
                    // then read the file and add its lines to the list with
                    // that already contains the new first line
                    linesToBeAppended.addAll(Files.readAllLines(filePath));
                    // append the extended text to the file (again),
                    // but this time overwrite the content
                    Files.write(filePath, linesToBeAppended,
                                StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println("Could not append text to file " 
                            + filePath.toAbsolutePath().toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not list files in " 
                + dirPath.toAbsolutePath().toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

> Another important difference is the flag in `Files.write`, which is not `APPEND` anymore, but `TRUNCATE_EXISTING` because you read the file into a list of `String` representing the lines, then you add that collection to the one that already contains the new first line. Afterwards, you just write the lines again including the new first line.

Comment: You're welcome, @GermanVaranytsya ... Pay attention to files other than .txt and maybe to file encoding, which may become troublesome.

Comment: one more question, if you could help me one more time... how can i add this string to the first line?

Comment: i have one more problem, if you could help one more time that would be nice! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57510342/error-java-nio-charset-malformedinputexception-input-length-1-java?noredirect=1#comment101488612_57510342

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is list all files in a directory, then work on each file. If that is the case you can do

```
File[] children = dir.listFiles();
for (File child: children) {
    if (child.isFile()) {
        // append text
    }
}
```

I've left out the code for appending the data since you say you already know how to do that. At this point it will simply be a case of applying that code to every file

Answer (score 0):

You can create a File holding your directory:

```
File directory = new File("pathOfYourDirectory");
```

you can then get all the subordinate files and directories like that:

```
File[] subDirectories = directory.listFiles();
```

Now you can iterate over this array. But you should check for each File whether it is a file. You can then take this file and append the text.

```
for (File subDir: subDirectories ) {
    if (subDir.isFile()) {
        // do your stuff
    }
}
```